# Does youtube employ forward error correction (FEC) in the transmission of video?

Tags: networking

I've noticed that youtube's video stream usually arrives via TCP/HTTP. However, I was told that youtube's servers employ FEC in video transmission. Seems rather comflicting to me - since TCP is reliable (ie lossless), so there would not be a need for FEC? Am I misssing something here?

Answer (score 1):

YouTube uses HTTP/TCP to buffer video into the flash player on its main site. The video is stored on Google Video's content distribution network. It's not streamed as much as just sent as fast as possible to your computer.
However, for 3g mobile handsets, m.youtube.com uses RTSP to stream video. So, YouTube uses both transfer methods.

Another thing to consider is that YouTube is popular because "it just works". RTSP isn't always supported well through routers, which would prevent that for use on the desktop.
Also of note, m.youtube.com doesn't stream the same video file as youtube.com.

If you do a some wireshark capture you should be able to capture the protocols and the video streams.

Yes, There is currently no FEC for the video streaming itself but on Chrome they have started to include some for requests inside their backbone (see Quic protocol).